# Mocking function in the same class java

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I am writing unit tests for a class, and I need to mock a call to a method in the same class.

```
//My class:
public class Class {
   public void functionA(arguments){
      ...
      String s3 = functionB(s1, s2);
   }

   public String functionB(String s1, String s2){
     ...
     return s3;
   }
}



//My Test:
@Test
public void functionA_Test(){
   Class class = new Class(dependency);
   Class spyClass = spy(class);

   mockString = "this is a mock";
   when(spyClass.functionB(any(),any()).thenReturn(mockString);

   spyClass.functionA(arguments);
}
```

When I debug the test function, after reaching  `when(spyClass.functionB(any(),any()).thenReturn(mockString);`, the program jumps to the main class, inside `functionB`, to run it. What I want is to automatically assign `s3=mockString` when calling `functionB` from `functionA`.

Comment: Why do you have to mock this call? If you test this `Class` (BTW: this is a *very* bad name), it is supposed to call its own method and that of all collaborators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `when(spyClass.functionB(any(),any()).thenReturn(mockString)`, it will indeed go through the real method in debug mode. But the method is mocked, and your `functionA` gets the `mockString`. It does work. I don't really understand why seing that you can go into debug mode into it is a problem.

To answer the question, using `mock` won't go through the method:

```
Class mockClass = mock(Class.class);

when(mockClass.functionB(any(),any())).thenReturn(mockString);
when(mockClass.functionA(arguments)).thenCallRealMethod();

mockClass.functionA(arguments);
```

**BUT** : this is a really bad test, you should never need to do that (spy or mock). If you test a class, then you test all of it. 
**If you need to mock a method to test another one, one of them probably belongs to another class.**

Comment: thanks, that's informative. I moved the logic of "functionB" to a different class. It needed to be mocked as it was in charge of working with AWS resources, which it couldn't do from a Test context.

Comment: Yeah that's perfect :) I usually do that too. And your comment perfectly shows why functionB belongs to another class. If it's in charge of something else (working with aws in your case), then the Single Responsibility Principle says to move it !

Answer (score 0):

Or in the situation when the tested class for eg. ClassA has a methodA() which calls inside methodB() and you are not interested at all of what happens inside methodB() then you could simply use an spy on the object representing the current class under test then set the custom behaviour of the methodB() using for eg. **Mockito.doNothing().when()** + **@Spy**.

```
@InjectMocks
@Spy
private ClassA testObj;

@BeforeEach
public void setUp() {

    super.setUp();
    
// the actual call of the methodB() will be totally ignored
    doNothing().when(testObj).methodB(input);
}

@Test
public void methodTest() {}
```